# How do I separate out the logs for different dataflows in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using NiFi 1.9.1 and am a sys admin for this cluster.

In the nifi-app.log, I get logs from all the processor groups.

Is there a way to separate the log lines out such that based on the processor groups a group of users sees logs only for those processors that they are interested in.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not supported in a current release of Apache NiFi. There is an [open Jira (NIFI-3065)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3065) to address this experience.

Comment: You could use NiFi itself to tail that log file and perform routing to various additional destinations (new log files, etc.) based on pattern matching.